# How to convert mins to hours? 75mins- 1:15

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

   public class TimeConversion{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int min= 0;  
    int hours = min / 60; 
        int minutes = min % 60;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the time in minutes:");
    minutes = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("The time is: ");

    System.out.printf("%d:%02d", hours, minutes);


}
```

}

How do i finish the code?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    int hours = min / 60; 
    int minutes = min % 60;
    System.out.print("The hours is "+hours+" and minutes is "+minutes);
```

**EDIT**

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

   public class TimeConversion{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   int minutes = min % 60;
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the time in minutes:");
   minutes = keyboard.nextInt();
   int hours = minutes / 60; 
   int minutes1 = minutes % 60;
   System.out.print("The hours is "+hours+" and minutes is "+minutes1);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't seem to work, but thanks.

Comment: hmm...what error u getting?

Comment: check my edited answer. Dont use `hours` since you didn't assign any value to it.

Comment: "min cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: @user2829266 `min` was your own variable containing the input value.  Did you remove it?

Comment: I replaced it with  int hours = min / 60; 
    int minutes = min % 60;

Comment: seriously...downvote for this answer?

Comment: you manage to get it?

Answer (score -1):

```
min = keyboard.nextInt();    

int hours = Integer.parseInt(Math.floor(min/60));
int minutes = min % 60;
System.out.print("The time is " + hours + ":" + minutes);
```